# How can I insert text before and after each line of a text file?

Tags: java, file, writefile

Below is my code that reads in a file, and then writes its contents to a new file. What I need to do is add in text between each line of text from the old file and put that in the new file. In this code, the file is read as a whole, so how do I change it to go through line by line and add text between each?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.List;

public class Webpage {
  public static String readTextFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
    return content;
  }

  public static List<String> readTextFileByLines(String fileName)throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));
    return lines;
  }

  public static void writeToTextFile(String fileName, String content)throws IOException {
    Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), content.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
  }

}
```

Comment: Conceptually, you'll need to write to a temp file, once you've finished reading the file, remove it and rename the temp into it's place

Comment: You've read the lines, now iterate through the list and write them one at a time. Are you asking how to iterate through a list? How to write in multiple steps?

Answer (score 0):

I think your readTextFileByLines will do what you want. You can iterate through the List and write out whatever you want before and after each line.

If you must use the readTextFile method, you could use split("\n") to turn the single big String (the whole file) into an array of Strings, one per line.

Hmm... the doc for Split (one argument) says that trailing empty strings won't be included in the result. So if your input file might contain empty lines at the end, you should use the two argument split with a very large second argument: split("\n", Long.MAX_VALUE);

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the text file line by line and add new lines where you wish.
2. Put the read values with new lines in a string per line separated by \n.
3. Write in new text file.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is re-write each line with the same string before and after each time than you can use this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    addLines("/Users/Hamish/Desktop/file1.txt", "/Users/Hamish/Desktop/file2.txt");
}

public static void addLines(String fileName, String secondFile) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = null;
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(secondFile, "UTF-8");
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.println("Random line before");
        writer.println(line);
        writer.println("Random line after");
    }
    br.close();
    writer.close();
}
```

Effectively it reads the txt file line by line and before and after each line it will print something you specify.

If you want at the end you can also write:

```
file.delete();
```

to remove the first file.

If what you want to write before and after each line is specific than unfortunately I can't help you.

Comment: this is helpful, and I don't need it to be that specific. I just need to write the same thing before and after each sentence, and a different thing before and after each capitalized sentence in the text file.